# how to set ResultSetMetaDataOptions property 1 in jdbcTemplate to retrieve tableName from resultSetMetadata

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm working on resultSetMetadata, when i'm getting the table name from resultsetmetadata rsmd.getTableName() then it returns "" (empty) string. I'm working with Oracle 10g DB.
So, I search then I got I have to set ResultSetMetaDataOptions property 1 then it will resolve but I don't know how to set it in jdbcTemplate in spring.
Now my question is
how to set ResultSetMetaDataOptions property 1 in jdbcTemplate to retrieve tableName from resultSetMetadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this option where you set connection options. In spring it is

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongjava" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
         <property name="ResultSetMetaDataOptions" value="1"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Smith, but I'm using (connection pooling) BasicDataSource to set connection in JdbcTemplate like,

BasicDataSource basicDataSource=new BasicDataSource();
basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("");
basicDataSource.setUrl("");
basicDataSource.setUsername("");
basicDataSource.setPassword("");

so, how to set in basicDataSource.

Comment: use method setProperty of BasicDataSource.

Comment: but there is no setProperty() in basicDataSource

Comment: I used basicDataSource.addConnectionProperty("ResultSetMetaDataOptions", "1");  but then also resultSetMetaData.getTableName() is not working